# Powershell script to move log files over network

Tags: powershell

Here's a PS script I have been developing to move files based on file age. This one writes to the event log as it progresses.I am new to Powershell and cannot figure out why the below script is not working.It is not running neither can I find any errors

```powershell
function WriteEventLog ($message, $entrytype)
{
 Write-EventLog -Logname "Application" -Source "MoveFilesScript" -Message $message -EntryType $entrytype -EventID 4001
}

$message = "Log file message goes here"
$entrytype = "Information"

WriteEventLog $message $entrytype

# File move related variables

$span = 30
$today = get-date
$CutoffTime = $today-$span
$SourcePath = "C:\tt\datfiles\Export\Intial"
$DestPath = "C:\tt\datfiles"

$files = dir $SourcePath

# empty arrays to hold file lists
$movedFiles = @()
$skippedFiles = @()

    foreach ($file in $files)
{
if ($file.lastwritetime -gt $CutoffTime)
{
$skippedFiles += $file.fullname
$message = "Not moving newer: " -join $file.fullname
$entrytype = "Information"
WriteEventLog $message $entrytype
}
else
{
$newname = $DestPath + "\" + $file.name + "-" + $file.lastwritetime.tostring("yyyy-MMM-dd")

$olderror = $error
move-item -ev a -path $file.fullname -destination $newname
$a.count
echo $movedFiles
if ($a.count -gt 0)
{
$message = $a[0].tostring()
$type = "Error"
WriteEventLog $message $type
}
else
{
$movedFiles += $file.fullname
}
}
```

Comment: Please add more information on why it fails or what happens when you try to run it.

Comment: _It is not running_ would not be a fault of the script but possible something like task scheduler.

Comment: I am running it by right-clicking and running with Powershell.Cannot see any error as the window is closing in micro-second

Comment: Well, open a PowerShell console and run the script from there, so the window does not close. What do you see?

Comment: I have a feeling this would work much better (and be much simpler) with robocopy.

Comment: I managed to run it by changing the execution policy

Comment: Now I am getting 2 new errors which are as: 1.Multiple ambigious overloads found for "op_subtraction" and the argument count:"2" 2.The term 'WriteEventlog' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet,funtion,script file.

Comment: Thanks guys the above script is working now. But since Alroc mentioned robocopy so thinking of using it. Any suggestions or idea? I can use robocopy in this script only or need to create new one?